# Any advantage of optimizing things like loops, conditional checks, variables.etc?

Tags: php, coding-style

I am curious to know that should we optimize loops, conditional checks, setting variables and unsetting them after they are used in PHP?

Is the foreach loop better then the for loop?

When I make IF-ELSE condition? Is it better to use ELSE clause or eliminate it altogether?

Does functions come in to play when optimizing code? Is `strstr` better than `strspos`?

Does these stuff important when coding or is it just personal preference?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Maintainable code is much more important than such optimizations in almost every situation.

Comment: It's at best micro optimization and definitely a total waste of your time.

Comment: Add the "meaning of life" to what you ask and you've got the broadest question ever :-) There so much things to take into account when optimizing your code, even if we don't speak about database connexion, database queries and client-side optimization there's a lot of things that can (or should) be done so you better look first somewhere else on the internet :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest focusing on the functional aspects of your code first. Make it easy to understand, easy to work on - maintainable.

Prematurely optimizing all of your code eats up lots of time, and may not be necessary.

Additionally, there are lots of myths / misconceptions about optimization and what is effective - making it all the more important to a) make sure there is an actual need for detailed optimization in the first place and b) invest the time to do it properly.